# package object definitions are not in scope

Tags: scala

Inside of my package com.example.common I have a package.scala file:

```
package com.example.common
import scala.concurrent.Future

package object common extends MyPackage {
}

trait MyPackage extends MyFutures {
}

trait MyFutures {
  type Funit = Future[Unit]
}
```

Now inside of this file I thought I can have the above in scope:

```
com.example.common.email

class EmailService() {
  def send(name: String): Funit = {

  }
}
```

But my alias type Funit isn't in scope and I get the error:

```
no found: type Funit
```

Comment: what is that `com.example.common.email` you have there? Are you sure that compiles?

Comment: And I took `com.example.com` as `common`, but maybe you were backspacing and were interrupted.

Comment: @som-snytt fixed that typo thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EmailService` is not in the package containing your package object.

Your package object is inside `com.package.common.common`

Also you *should* name name your package object according to the package:

> A package object package object `p` extends `t` adds the members of template to the package `p`. There can be only one package object per package. The standard naming convention is to place the definition above in a file named `package.scala` that's located in the directory corresponding to package `p`.

So you should have the following

- a file named `com/example/common/package.scala`
- containing package object `common`
- declared inside package `com.example`

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

package object common extends MyPackage {
}

trait MyPackage extends MyFutures {
}

trait MyFutures {
  type Funit = Future[Unit]
}

// in the same file (you mentioned "Now inside of this file I thought I can have the above in scope:")
package common {
  package email {

    class EmailService() {
      def send(name: String): Funit = ???
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: If I have my EmailService inside of com.example.common package, why doesn't it work?  the package is 'com.example.common' and the top of my EmailService file has the package 'com.example.common'.

Comment: Your package object is inside com.package.common.common

Answer (score 0):

This way, since you're already in the common package:

```
package com.example.common

import scala.concurrent.Future

object `package` extends MyPackage {
}

trait MyPackage extends MyFutures {
}

trait MyFutures {
  type Funit = Future[Unit]
}
```

and to make common._ visible:

```
package com.example.common
package email

class EmailService() {
  def send(name: String): Funit = ???
}
```

Comment: You named the object package?  I have ```package object common extends MyPackage```  i'm confused!

Comment: Yes, a package object is actually an object named package. Sometimes this form is helpful. The way you had it, it actually adds a nested package named common.common.